# Multiple SQL on the same SparkContext concurrently

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to develop a Spark application that will use streaming to create `RDDs`, then convert RDDs of the `DStream` to `DataFrame` and run `SQL` query, which is similar to this [Spark example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaSqlNetworkWordCount.java)

The challenge is, instead of running one `SQL`, I need to run multiple SQLs. I am not sure if DataFrame is threadsafe so I can create threads which takes SQLContext and can run in parallel for the queries and the 'action', or there is a way i can do it cleaner in Spark. The following how I can do it sequentially, but I want to do it concurrently.

```
    DataFrame wordsDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, JavaRecord.class); 


     // Register as table 
     wordsDataFrame.registerTempTable("words"); 

     // Do word count on table using SQL and print it 
     DataFrame wordCountsDataFrame = 
         sqlContext.sql("select word, count(*) as total from words group by word"); 
     System.out.println("========= " + time + "========="); 

     // Do word count AGAIN on table using SQL and print it 
     DataFrame wordCountsDataFrame2 = 
         sqlContext.sql("select word, count(*) as total from words where len(word) > 10 group by word"); 
     System.out.println("========= " + time + "========="); 
     wordCountsDataFrame2.show();
```